# SQL query when result is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
USER     itemnumber     datebought (YYYYmmDD)

a           1            20160101
b           2            20160202
c           3            20160903
d           4            20160101
```

Now I have to show the total number of items bought by each user after date 20160202 (2 february 2016)

I used

```
SELECT USER, COUNT(itemnumber)<br/>
FROM TABLE<br/>
WHERE datebought >= 20160202<br/>
GROUP BY USER<br>
```

It gives me results

```
b        1
c        1
```

but I want like this

```
a      0
b      1
c      1
d      0
```

Please tell me what is the most quick method / efficient method to do that ?

Comment: You forgot to tag other **RDBMS** products like `postgresql`, `db2` etc.

Comment: Can't, it allows only 5 :) I think it was a sarcastic comment :p

Comment: Why do you tag several different dbms products, and then accept a product specific answer for one of those products!!! Don't tag products not invoved!!!

Comment: @Aiden Yes it was a sarcastic comment ;-) My intention was to explain you that you should always use relevant tags to get a specific answer. The syntax for different database products would be different. The answer you accepted is only for `sqlserver` and won't work on other databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this,

```
       DECLARE @table TABLE
  (
     [USER]     VARCHAR(1),
     itemnumber INT,
     datebought DATE
  ) 
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('a',1,'20160101'),
('b',2,'20160202'),
('b',2,'20160202'),
('b',2,'20160202'),
('c',3,'20160903'),
('d',4,'20160101')

SELECT *
FROM   @TABLE

SELECT [USER],
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN datebought >= '20160202' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS ITEMCOUNT
FROM   @TABLE
GROUP  BY [USER]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) What if there are more than two items for USER b then the statement "THEN 1" should be changed to SUM (itembought) ? otherwise it will always give 1 ?

Comment: It there are two items for a particular user then it returns 2. ( case return always 1 or 0 based on date check) so sum of 1 plus 1 gives two. Please refer the updated answer. I have provided sample data to your scenario.

Comment: WOW that's genius! It is working! I will try to understand the nice logic you wrote and will use it :) Thanks a lot "NewUser" :) Cheers! I think question is solved with your answer!

Comment: You are always welcome. Please select my answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SELECT USER, COUNT(itemnumber)
       FROM TABLE
       WHERE datebought >= 20160202
       GROUP BY USER
```

Comment: Sorry that was typing error. I used group by USER but it gave me results like that. I was thinking of using CASE WHEN THEN ELSE or some left join but don't know how this one will be done. Using datebought > 20160202 simply removes the USER a and USER b from result.

Answer (score 0):

Though this query won't be a good idea for the large amount of data:

```
SELECT USER, COUNT(itemnumber)
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE datebought >= 20160202
 GROUP BY USER
 UNION
SELECT DISTINCT USER, 0
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE datebought < 20160202
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right :) I think it is better to go with some other solution. Can we do it with CASE statement ?

Comment: @Aiden: Please try with my answer I posted just now

Comment: I think the query performance with CASE will be almost (if not exactly) the same, since it will have to read all values for user, itemnumber and datebought anyway. Depending on the data, the version with union could be even faster, since it won't have to do sum for the values with datebought < 20160202.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE tempdb
GO  
 DROP TABLE test1
 CREATE TABLE test1(a NVARCHAR(10), ino INT, datebought INT)
INSERT INTO dbo.test1
        ( a, ino, datebought )
VALUES  ( 'a' ,          1    ,        20160101)
INSERT INTO dbo.test1
        ( a, ino, datebought )
VALUES  ( 'b' ,          2    ,        20160202)

INSERT INTO dbo.test1
        ( a, ino, datebought )
VALUES  ( 'c' ,          3    ,        20160903)

INSERT INTO dbo.test1
        ( a, ino, datebought )
VALUES  ( 'd' ,          4   ,        20160101)

SELECT * FROM dbo.test1

SELECT a, COUNT(ino) OVER(PARTITION  BY a) FROM dbo.test1
WHERE datebought>=20160202
UNION ALL
SELECT a,  0 FROM dbo.test1
WHERE datebought<20160202
ORDER BY a
```

Comment: Why do you need over here?

Comment: you can modify datebought to date/datetime and refactor the query as needed